# Expectation and law of large numbers

Tags: expected-value

A fair color dice has two green sides, three red sides, and one blue side. It is rolled an infinite number of times. Let
$$
S_n:=\text { number of } \text { ,,green''} - \text{ number of ,,blue'' }
$$
be the difference of the number of dice result ,,green'' and the number of dice result ,,blue'', each up to the $n$th roll, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I want to find a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
P\left(\frac{S_n}{n} \stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} c\right)=1.
$$

---

My idea goes like this: We choose for $c$ the expected value from the random variable $S_1$: difference after one execution, because we use the strong law of large numbers. It is therefore valid
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_1]=\mathbb{E}[X-Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{2}{6}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}=c
$$
where $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is expectation of green and $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ is expectation of blue. Does this approach make sense? Do I have to verify $\mathbb{E}[S_1^2]<\infty?$

Comment: Yes that is correct. Here I assume you mean to define the Bernoulli random variables $X_i = 1_{\{\mbox{roll $i$ yields green}\}}$ and similar for $Y_i$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, and $Z_i=X_i-Y_i$. It is obvious that $E[Z_i]$ is finite since $Z_i \in \{0, 1, -1\}$.